# Are these 2 statments equivalent?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

Conditional proposition 1: **If** it is sunny, **then** I'll go.

Conditional proposition 2: I will go **unless** it is **not** sunny.

Let's decompose them as simple propositions.

A: It is sunny.

B: I will go.

Thus re-write the previous 2 conditional propositions:

1: **If** A, **then** B

2: B, **unless  not** A

In my opinion, the truth table for each of them are:

1:

```
A--------B--------Proposition 1

T--------T-------------T

T--------F-------------F

F--------T-------------T

F--------F-------------T
```

2:

```
A--------B--------Proposition 2

T--------T-------------T

T--------F-------------F

F--------T-------------F   <---- here is the difference.

F--------F-------------T
```

So I think these 2 statements are not equivalent, but the famous *Discrete Mathematics and its Applications* by *Kenneth H. Rosen* indicates that they **are** equivalent.

Could someone shed some light on this?

Another post is made here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129691/are-these-two-statements-equivalent

Comment: would this be better answered on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: No impropriety, just trying to help you get to the place that might give you the best chance of success, there are lots of niche  stackexchange sites that most people don't know exist. Good luck with getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the word "unless."  Unless is really describing when something is not true.

Conditional proposition 1: If it is sunny, then I'll go.

Conditional proposition 2: I will go unless it is not sunny.  I.E. If it is not sunny, I will not go.

1: If A, then B

2: If Not B, then Not A

A ⇒ B is the same as ¬B ⇒ ¬A.  I can't remember the exact name of the law, but it's easy to derive.  Use the implication law to convert it to ¬A ∨ B and B ∨ ¬A and the commutative law will change B ∨ ¬A to ¬A ∨ B

Comment: I agree with your derivation. But I still don't know why there's difference between the 2 truth tables.

Comment: Converting "Unless" from English to logic can be confusing.  Doing a quick google for "propositional logic unless" you'll find a few useful explanations:  http://cr.yp.to/2005-261/bender1/Lo.pdf (search for "unless") has a pretty good explanation.  Here's another: http://wiki.gonzaga.edu/alfino/index.php/Propositional_Logic#.22Unless.22

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the confusing conversion of "unless" between English and logic. I think that could be the cause of my problem. I will read the material you providied.